# How to deal with this untrusted program

Tags: security, ip

The program is [IPFS](http://ipfs.io/). I do not fully trust the program, how should I keep it from making changes to my system outside of its designated folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I keep it from making changes to my system outside of its designated folders

Looks like they use a separately mounted filesystem and you can use fuse with it. So nobody should be able to get outside that (unless you let them).

There are 2 important notices on the [installation page](http://ipfs.io/docs/install/):

- "Use the optional [fuse](http://ipfs.io/docs/install/#install-fuse)".

> FUSE  (Filesystem  in  Userspace)  is  a simple interface for userspace
>          programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel. FUSE  also
>          aims  to provide a secure method for non privileged users to create and
>          mount their own filesystem implementations.

- They will provide [signed releases](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/957).